# TextBox not showing text inside round brackets

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm writing an application that allows a user to add a simple piece of information for a server into a database.  However, if the server already contains that information, the information is displayed and the user is informed that they cannot add another for the same server.

My code is as follows:

```
        ComboBox caller = sender as ComboBox;
        ComboBoxItem selected = (ComboBoxItem)caller.Items.GetItemAt(caller.SelectedIndex);

        _CurrentServer = (string)selected.Content;

        _SQLManager.UpdateServerInfo(_CurrentServer);

        if (_SQLManager.ServerID != -1)
        {
            BVWTextBox.Text = "BVW 00000 (0000-00-00t00_00_00)";
            if (_SQLManager.ServerBVW != "")
            {
                BVWTextBox.IsEnabled = false;
                BVWInfoTextBlock.Text = "Server " + _CurrentServer + " already has a BVW.  Please update the BVWinstead of adding a new one. ";
                BVWInfoTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                BVWTextBox.IsEnabled = true;
                BVWnfoTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }
```

Currently I'm just putting something in the form of what the BVW # would look like, which is:

BVW 00000 (0000-00-00t00_00_00) Where the 0's are replaced by #'s.

However all that shows up in the TextBox is:

BVW 00000

Tried setting it to BVW 00000 (wut) And it showed properly.

What's going on here?

Edit:  TextBox xaml:

```
<TextBox FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Name="BVWTextBox"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="177" Canvas.Left="101" Canvas.Top="94">
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: Did you search for all usages of `BVWTextBox.Text`? The Text might be changed somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Or maybe that line of code is executed twice, and the second time around, the value is different.

Comment: Please show your form markup for BVWTextBox. Do you have any validators or length restrictions on this control?

Comment: @mjw Edited with xaml for BVWTextBox

Comment: @Meta-Knight I single stepped the code, it's getting set to the correct value, but won't display inside the brackets.  It's the only place that the text gets set in the code.